# How to make NodeJS work in a linux web server. What are the steps necessary, and coding and setup procedures following good practices

Tags: node.js, lamp

I recently learned node and am coming from a LAMP stack. I don't uderstand how node.js file will be served by the Linux servers that I have been using right now.
I understand everything while working from a linux terminal but really don't get how to make Node JS work in a linux web server . If it can work at all with the lamp stack, what are the steps necessary, and coding and setup procedures following good practices. Please give a comprehensive answer explaining the physics of how it works or mention some links.

I get the tutorials I was learning from, we are running a server from a terminal but how does it all fit in the real Linux server (because I think it should as It is running in the linux termninals ) or do we really have to buy special node js servers, if there are any particular ones for them?

Correct me if I am wrong but I suppose it has something to configure with the htaccess file. I dunno still, please shed some good enough lights.

---

- Additional Help

  1. If someone could also direct me how to proceed to a middleware like express or any other alternative (mentioning the best ones and the merits).
  2. Also, I would like to see some examples of a basic/trivial thing built with node. If there are some online examples (A repo or article with live demos & source) to refer to for using as a bolierplate.

---

I really want to get my hands dirty with Node and start building something. It's itching me though that I don't know how to deploy a node website and how to build something deployable (or start with the right infrastructure). and secondly how does the middleware (and alternatives) are gonna work then if deployed and what are the practices and how to choose one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Node.JS work as opposed to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391227/how-does-node-js-work-as-opposed-to-php)

Comment: I don't think that the scope of the question is the same as the one indicated as "duplicate".

Comment: @mingos the scope of the question is entirely too broad and needs to be closed either way

Comment: "I don't nuderstand how node.js file will be served by the Linux servers" - if I understand correctly, this is the question (albeit not exactly phrased as such). I fail to see the breadth that would deserve a closing vote.

Comment: The question lacks any indication that the OP has any idea what a web server is or how it relates to the server that such a web server runs on. -- immediately too broad. The dupe at least sheds some light on the php vs node.js aspect of the question.

Comment: I beg to differ.

Comment: I have the complete idea of how a web server works, I have been developing for the frontend for quite some time now and also laid hands on php a bit and maintain a lot of websites on linux servers.

@mingos is quite right about what I want to ask.

I understand that how I am not clear with my question and so I will update the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has an inbuilt functionality that allows you to spawn an HTTP server, so technically you don't need a LAMP stack. Specifically, you don't need Apache or Nginx.

On Node.js website, you can find the following snippet:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

If you put this in a file, say, index.js, and run the file (`node index.js`), a web server will be created and it will listen on the host/port 127.0.0.1:3000.

Now, this is good for development purposes, but not necessarily for a production environment. In production, you need two more elements of the puzzle: a **reverse proxy** and a way to **daemonise the node server**.

### Reverse proxy

Every node.js application you run will listen on a specific host and port. The port must be unique for every app. Typically, the host will be 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and the port will be >1024 (as this does not require root access), but any outside traffic will be coming through your server's public IP via ports 80 and 443. You have to direct such traffic to the apps listening on different ports. This is where a reverse proxy comes into play.

A reverse proxy is basically Apache or Nginx server listening on port 80 or 443 (depending on whether you use HTTP or HTTPS). It will proxy (or "redirect") the incoming traffic to the node server of your choosing. As I haven't used Apache for years, I can only offer an example Nginx configuration for a virtual host:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This would do exactly what I described above: listen on port 80 for any requests to the domain name "example.com" and proxy them to 127.0.0.1:3000.

If you're planning to use Apache, please google for an equivalent vhost configuration, as I'm unable to provide one off the top of my head.

### Node.js server as a daemon

The issue with node.js servers is that they will not survive throwing an uncaught error or a host machine reboot. You need to make sure that the node.js server will respawn after either of these occurs. There are a couple of ways to achieve that; the simplest one I know of is **using forever and a crontab entry**.

You will first need forever to achieve this. [Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) is an npm package that will daemonise your node servers.

```
npm install -g forever
```

Go through forever's documentation to learn all about it, but in a nutshell, all you need to do is create a **forever.json** file that contains configuration for your node.js servers and use that file to start your apps.

The config might look like this:

```
[
    {
        "uid": "my-app",
        "append": true,
        "watch": true,
        "script": "src/index.js",
        "sourceDir": "/path/to/my-app",
        "command": "/path/to/node",
        "args": ["--port=3000", "--env=production"]
    }
]
```

You can now start all your apps using this command:

```
forever start /path/to/forever.json
```

Bear in mind that forever will not let you use individual environment variables per app, so if you plan on running multiple apps (node servers), you will need to either hard code their ports or, preferably, set them in a different manner, e.g. using command line parametres, as shown above.

That takes care of respawning the apps in case they fail. The reboot situation is solved by crontab.

Type `crontab -e` and at the end of the opened file, append the following:

```
@reboot /path/to/node path/to/forever start /path/to/forever.json >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will start all your apps using forever once - right after a reboot.

Alternatives to the forever + crontab approach are available. You can google for them, however, I find the combo very satisfactory, easy to set up and use.

I hope this answers your question fully. In case you have any further doubts, please comment.

Comment: That is a possibility.

Comment: @mingos I appreciate the effort you put into this post but sometimes downvotes come from simply answering a question that should be closed. *:shrug:*

Comment: @SterlingArcher a downvote is supposed to be an indication that an answer is wrong, not useful, misleading, etc. Downvoting an answer because the *question* is something I simply can't understand or agree with. That also makes me want to just quit using SO altogether. Why bother, after all?

Comment: I realise that, I'm just replying.

Comment: I have 2 questions
1.How and in which file do i set the following code up? (to use reverse proxy of NGINX)

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

2. I don't understand most of this part "Node.js server as a daemon" & why do we need multiple node servers for a single site. I am very new to all this, I have a hostgator hosting and I dont know if I have NGINX..

Comment: Then check what server you have. If it's a shared host, especially if made primarily for setting up PHP sites, Apache is much more common. I don't know what the vhost file should look like for Apache, but you can easily google that. As for the deamon part - what don't you understand exactly?